# Removing images from paragraph tags

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code which pulls out the blockquote and puts my WordPress post content in `<p>` tags.

```
<?php
    $content = preg_replace('/<blockquote>(.*?)<\/blockquote>/', '', get_the_content());
    $content = wpautop($content); // Add paragraph-tags
    $content = str_replace('<p></p>', '', $content); // remove empty paragraphs
    echo $content;
?>
```

However it puts the images in `<p>` tags which I don't want

Comment: 1. What exactly you **do** want? 2. Did you try to write something yourself? 3. How does the output looks like?

Comment: You will probably need to run another ```preg_replace``` for the images. [Here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7090/stop-wordpress-wrapping-images-in-a-p-tag) is an example of a pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that should do it (not tested).

```
<?php
    $content = preg_replace('/<blockquote>(.*?)<\/blockquote>/', '', get_the_content());
    $content = wpautop($content); // Add paragraph-tags
    $content = str_replace('<p></p>', '', $content); // remove empty paragraphs
    $content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content); // remove paragraphs around img tags
    echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: seems to work thank you! I know alot of people say not to use pregreplace

Comment: Maybe because of the danger of code injection, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

On the line after the `str_replace` you could use this [domDocument](http://php.net/domDocument) method:

```php
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagname('img');
$removeList = array();
foreach ($images as $domElement) {
    $removeList[] = $domElement;
}
foreach ($removeList as $toRemove) {
    $toRemove->parentNode->removeChild($toRemove);
}
$content = $dom->saveHTML();
```

*(ps: this will also give you a non `preg_replace` method, not that it really matters)*

Comment: I can never seem to put in domDocuments, they always seem to throw errors or just not work

Comment: I have been using the above for years. Zero errors, always works. No complicated `preg_replace()`.

Comment: oh ok, its a prob on my end then. I usually just put these types of codes in <php> tags